# How to add a horizontal scrollbar to selectInput widget in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to add a horizontal scroll bar to selectInput as some choices are not fully visible as highlighted. See pic
[image]

ui.R

```
                                      tabPanel("IPL Match",
                                                                      h4('Analyze an IPL match'),
                                                                      sidebarPanel(
                                                                          selectInput('matchFunc', 'Select match function', matchFuncs),
                                                                          selectInput('match', 'Select IPL match ', IPLMatches,selectize=FALSE, size=12),
                                                                          uiOutput("selectTeam"),
                                                                          radioButtons("plotOrTable", label = h4("Plot(static,interactive) or table"),
                                                                                       choices = c("Plot(interactive)" = 2, "Plot(static)" = 1, "Table" = 3),
                                                                                       selected = 2,inline=T)

                                                                      ),
                                                                      mainPanel(
                                                                          uiOutput("plotOrPrintIPLMatch"),
                                                                          column(7, offset=4,
                                                                                 tags$h5((tags$i("Designed and developed by Tinniam V Ganesh"))),
                                                                                 tags$h5((tags$i("May 25, 2021"))),
                                                                                 tags$h6("Data source Cricsheet: http://cricsheet.org/"),
                                                                                 tags$a(href="https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yorkr/index.html", " Based on R package yorkr")


                                                                          )
                                                                      )
```

server.R

```
 # Analyze and display IPL Match plot
  output$IPLMatchPlots <- renderPlot({
    printOrPlotMatch(input, output,"IPL")

  })

  output$IPLMatchPlotly <- renderPlotly({
    printOrPlotMatch(input, output,"IPL")

  })

  # Analyze and display IPL Match table
  output$IPLMatchPrint <- renderTable({
    a <- printOrPlotMatch(input, output,"IPL")
    a

  })
  # Output either a table or a plot
  output$plotOrPrintIPLMatch <-  renderUI({
    # Check if output is a dataframe. If so, print
    if(is.data.frame(scorecard <- printOrPlotMatch(input, output,"IPL"))){
      tableOutput("IPLMatchPrint")
    }
    else{ #Else plot
      if(input$plotOrTable == 1){
        plotOutput("IPLMatchPlots")
      } else{
        plotlyOutput("IPLMatchPlotly")
      }

    }

  })
```

I  tried adding width = 150px and width = "150%". Both did not work. All suggestions welcome.

After adding code by @YBS
[image]

Comment: Added ui.R and server.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have many `selectInput`s, it may be best to define a class for the appropriate `selectInput`s and apply the new style using CSS to only those `selectInput`s of interest (by wrapping in a `div`) as shown below.

```
choices <- c(rep('A very loooooong sentence.',8))

library(shiny)
u <- fluidPage(

  # tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}'))),
  tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", '.myclass .shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}')),
  
  
  tags$div(id="myclass1", class="myclass", selectInput(inputId = "in", label = "Choose", choices = choices,
              selectize = F, size = 5, width = "150px")),
  selectInput(inputId = "im", label = "Choose2", choices = choices,
              selectize = F,  width = "230px"
              )
)

s <- function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

Your `ui` is more than 2400 lines.  I do not have time to review it.  You should try to put this `tags$head(...)` on line 26.

[image: output]

Comment: No it did not work. I think there is some CSS file that needs to be added besides the tag$head

Comment: Perhaps you should try in a different browser.

Comment: I could not figure where exactly the code should go. Is it just above the   tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}'))), 
   selectInput('match', 'Select IPL match ', IPLMatches,selectize=FALSE, size=12),        Please clarify.

Comment: It could be above `sidebarPanel()` or above `selectInput()`.  As you have not posted a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with some sample data, I cannot test it.

Comment: I tried it right at top and also just above selectInput.Did not seem to work. The complete code for the Shiny app is here https://github.com/tvganesh/gpp2021-6. The selectInput is in line 95 of ui.R. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Added the following lines      tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", '.myclass .shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}')),
                                                                              
                                                                              tags$div(id="myclass1", class="myclass", selectInput('match', 'Select IPL match ', IPLMatches,selectize=FALSE,size=18,width='1000px')), as width='150px' only diplayed 1/3 of list box.  Still not working in Chrome. Also tried Firefox & afari. No luck..

Comment: If the above (MRE) code works, when you run "as is" in your RStudio, you should be able to implement it in your code.  Not sure why it does not work.

Comment: Tried in RStudio also, don't see it. Possibly because there is another widget down. Not sure why, though I desperately need it to work. Anyway thanks.

Comment: it works. In my Mac, the scrollbar does not show, but it is there and I can drag left or right. I realised this when I just tried your short code. Then I added to my app and I works!! Many thanks!!!