# R Shiny wrap text in checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

i have a sideBarLayout with a sidebar to select which columns to show. The column names are very long. Is there a way to fold or collapse these long names so that they fit in the sidebar?

Picture below to show the problem.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Just a thought, if there's a shortened version of the names that's still informative, why not rename the source data frame?  Also, can you give a few examples of the full structure of the names and what parts you want to see in the shortened ones?

Comment: So, I don't really want to see all the abundances. I could abbreviate it as Abu.Norm.FXXS1T12 ... but is there no way to work around that and just make the sidebar horizontally scrollable?

Comment: There's a discussion here of how to do that (add a scrollbar to the group rather than the whole sidebar) which might help?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69284205/16730940  I'll keep looking to see if there's a more general option.

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help). I'd use a `selectizeInput(..., multiple = TRUE)` instead of a `checkboxGroupInput` in this scenario.

Comment: you could also just look at `stringr::str_wrap`